# how to format created date to iso UTC format Sharepoint designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

How can i format this date

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(@Created_x0020_Date,'0;#','')"></xsl:value-of>
```

to something like this UTC format  - "2012-01-13T16:14:21Z"

Answer (score 0):

While I dont have the 100% answer to this but I can suggest you do something like this

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(@ArticleStartDate, 2057, 3)"/>
```

Check this article 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshuag/archive/2009/03/25/custom-date-formats-in-sharepoint-xsl.aspx